# Sorting JSON data server-side in Java before being returned

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have built a new web service which returns some JSON data, using a pre-existing class, which returns many results. Here is an example of the JSON structure for the first object in the array:

```
0: {
  "bookingId": 3189,
  "meetingId": 3181,
  "meetingDetails": 
       {
     "MeetingId": 3181,
     "name": "Meeting of Kings",
     "cutOffDate": 1484583728748,
     "availableOnline": false,
       },
  "primaryAccountId": null,
  "primaryAccountName": null,
  "secondaryAccountId": null,
  "secondaryAccountName": null,
  "attended": false,
  "notes": null,
  "bookingFromTime": [
    2016,
    11,
    2,
    18,
    5,
    0,
    0
              ],
  "bookingToTime":   [
    2016,
    11,
    2,
    18,
    10,
    0,
    0
              ],

  },
{
```

I need to be able to sort, server-side, by the **meetingDetails** object. So that, for each meeting, there can be many bookings. I'm fairly new so this fairly basic web service is the extent of my knowledge.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: If all objects are in an array, then what is '0:' ? JSON array elements do not have a key. If all is returned in a JSON array, you need to sort the collection in Java prior sending it to the front-end. The order of the elements are always maintained.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle You are correct, this is just how it is returned using a REST client.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your requirement, do you mean you have `an array` of objects(let's call it `Booking`), which each contains an field `MeetingDetail`, and then you want to sort the array of `bookings` by their `meetingDetail` and then return the array as JSON? Could you please give more explanation, with desc of input and desired output?

Comment: @shizhz Thank you for trying to understand, sorry my explanation isn't great.  Yes, it is an array of many 'Booking' objects. Each booking object has a reference to a 'meetingDetails' object, which will appear within each booking object. I need to get a list of many 'Booking' objects, sorted by the 'meetingDetails' object. So, my output would be that each meetingDetails object contains a list of Booking objects. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for your extra info, I was really thinking I got your idea until I reached `So, my output would be that each meetingDetails object contains a list of Booking objects`, do you just want to sort 'Bookings' by 'meetingDetails', or do you want to group your 'bookings' by 'meetingDetail'? I think it'll be clear if you could give an example input and desired output.

Comment: @shizhz I would like to group my bookings by meetingDetail. I will update the post to contain more information.

Comment: @greenTree You need to make clear what your expected output is. Your JSON is not the complete JSON. You should also post some code where you generate the JSON output.